# Loop for ansible arrays

Tags: ansible

I am registering two variables using ansible task and result of which is-

```
"pathlist": [
        "/dir1/dir2/dir3",
        "/dir1/dir2/dir3/abc.txt",
        "/dir1/dir2/dir3/testme"
    ]

"pathexists": [
        true,
        true,
        false
    ]
```

I want to print the output as -

```
"/dir1/dir2/dir3" -- true
"/dir1/dir2/dir3/abc.txt" -- true
"/dir1/dir2/dir3/testme" -- false
```

I am using following piece of code for printing the final result-
- set_fact:
    output: "{{ item.0 }} -- {{ item.1 }}\n"
  with_nested:
    - "{{ pathlist  }}"
    - "{{ pathexists }}"

- debug: var=output

I guess, I am missing something. Any help will be of great use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*with_together* is what you are looking for

```
 tasks:
   - debug: msg="{{ item.0 }} -- {{ item.1 }}"
     with_together:
       - "{{ pathlist }}"
       - "{{ pathexists }}"
```

gives:

```
    "msg": "/dir1/dir2/dir3 -- True"
    "msg": "/dir1/dir2/dir3/abc.txt -- True"
    "msg": "/dir1/dir2/dir3/testme -- False"
```